# TSQL Sub Queries Are Messing Up Group By

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, subquery

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide. So far I've been unable to find anything like this in my searches here or elsewhere but I'm betting it's more because I don't know of a standard way to describe the issue/question.

I'm building a lookup code from data which resides in two different tables.  We have menu items which can be associated with one or more choices. In this case we are dealing with curries (item) which are served with a type of meat (choice) and a type of rice (another choice found in the same choice table). The complete PLU is the item level SKU concatenated with choice level SKU's for each of the 2 choice categories.  An example of a full PLU is:

```
'CuMaBfWh'
```

where 'CuMa' is the item level SKU and 'Bf' and 'Wh' are the choice-level sku's respectively.  I am able to build the PLU using sub-queries (don't like it) within an outer query. The issue is that this method does not allow me to group the data correctly.  Sample tables, query, problematic output and correct output follow.

**Given sample data in these tables:**

**Ticket**

```
i_ticket_id

    3
```

**TicketItem**

```
i_ticket_item_id  i_ticket_id  i_menu_item_id   dt_when

        1                  3           1        '02/08/2015 16:42:00'
        2                  3           1        '02/08/2015 16:42:00'
        3                  3           1        '02/08/2015 16:42:00'
        4                  3           1        '02/08/2015 16:42:00'
```

**MenuItem**

```
i_menu_item_id      s_mi_sku    

    1               'CuMa'
```

**ChoiceItem**

```
i_choice_item_id     i_ticket_item_id   i_choice_id

    1                   1                   2
    2                   1                   8
    3                   2                   1
    4                   2                   8
    5                   3                   4 
    6                   4                   9
```

**Choice**

```
i_choice_id     s_choice_sku

   1            'Ch'
   2            'Bf'
   3            'Po'
   4            'To'
   5            'St'
   6            'Ve'
   7            'Sh$'
   8            'Wh'
   9            'Br'    
  10            'Fr$'
  11            'Nr'
```

**Correct Output would look as follows:**

```
Date        PLU        Qty  Amount
----        ---        ---  ------
02/08/2015  CuMaBfWh    2    19.00
02/08/2015  CuMaChWh    1     9.50
02/08/2015  CuMaToBr    1     9.50
```

**My Problematic Query:**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ti.dt_when, 101) [Date], 
       -- Start building the PLU with the sku from the item level
       mi.s_mi_sku
       -- Continue building the PLU by adding on the choice sku from the chosen meat
    +   (SELECT TOP(1) c1.s_choice_sku 
     FROM Choices c1 
        INNER JOIN 
              ChoiceItem ci1 ON ci1.i_choice_id = c1.i_choice_id AND c1.s_choice_sku IN ('Ch', 'Bf', 'Po', 'To', 'St', 'Ve', 'Sh$') 
         WHERE ci1.i_ticket_item_id = ti.i_ticket_item_id)
       -- Complete the PLU by adding on the choice sku from the chosen rice
    +   (SELECT TOP(1) c2.s_choice_sku 
         FROM Choices c2 
            INNER JOIN 
              ChoiceItem ci2 ON ci2.i_choice_id = c2.i_choice_id AND c2.s_choice_sku IN ('Wh', 'Br', 'Fr$', 'Nr') 
         WHERE ci2.i_ticket_item_id = ti.i_ticket_item_id) [PLU], 
    SUM(ti.f_ticketitem_share_qty) [Qty], 
    SUM(ti.c_ticketitem_net_price) [Amount]
FROM Ticket t
    INNER JOIN
 TicketItem ti on t.i_ticket_id = ti.i_ticket_id
    INNER JOIN
 MenuItem mi on ti.i_menu_item_id = mi.i_menu_item_id
WHERE ti.dt_when >= '2/8/2015 04:00:00' and ti.dt_when <= '2/9/2015 03:59:00' and mi.s_mi_sku = 'CuMa'
GROUP BY mi.s_mi_sku, ti.dt_when, ti.i_ticket_item_id
```

**which produces the following problematic output:**

```
Date        PLU        Qty   Amount
----        ---        ---   ------
02/08/2015  CuMaBfWh    1    9.50
02/08/2015  CuMaChWh    1    9.50
02/08/2015  CuMaToBr    1    9.50
02/08/2015  CuMaBfWh    1    9.50
```

I've believe this to be a result of the need to include the ti.i_ticket_item_id in the 'GROUP BY' clause but I can't figure out another way to do it.

Any thoughts? All constructive advice/criticism is appreciated!

Thanks,
David

Comment: are you able to change the database design? If yes, then your problem and its solution becomes much simpler?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot modify the design. This is a backend for a 3rd party POS system. I'm extracting sales data for import into an inventory/menu-costing program.

Comment: In the ticket item table, is ticket_item_id unique in the table regardless of ticket_id? or is ticket_item_id  unique for each ticket_id?

Comment: can the person ordering make a maximum of two choices from the choices table?

Comment: are you able to change the database design  for the inventory/menu-costing program

Comment: Answers to above questions:  1. Each ticket_item_id is unique regardless of ticket_id. You can think of Ticket as a Header with one or many TicketItems.  2. The person ordering can, in some cases request more than one choice per category.  This is why I am using Top(1) in the sub queries.  It means there will sometimes be incomplete/incorrect data but we've made the choice not to try to reflect all possible PLU combinations in the Inventory package.  3. The inventory/menu-costing program is also 3rd party and cannot be changed.

Comment: Given that these are the aggregated columns can you provide info on them please `SUM(ti.f_ticketitem_share_qty) [Qty]` & `SUM(ti.c_ticketitem_net_price) [Amount]`

Comment: ti.f_ticketitem_share_qty is used to reflect whether the item was shared by 2 or more people.  Items can be split into halves or thirds and moved to other people - at which point they then get a new ticket_Item entry in TicketItem.

ti.c_ticketitem_net_price is the non-taxed sale value of the item after all discounts and any shares.have been applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand how `ti.f_ticketitem_share_qty` fits into things so I have just added some aggregation so that the group by works as expected. Note too that the data you provided didn't include the case where 2 customers ordered the same thing on the same order so I added data so that the grouping showed something relevant.

```
declare @Ticket table (i_ticket_id int)
insert into @Ticket values(3)

declare @TicketItem table (i_ticket_item_id int,  i_ticket_id int,  i_menu_item_id int, dt_when datetime)
insert into @TicketItem
values
    (1,3,1,'02/08/2015 16:42:00'),
    (2,3,1,'02/08/2015 16:42:00'),
    (3,3,1,'02/08/2015 16:42:00'),
    (4,3,1,'02/08/2015 16:42:00'),
    (5,3,1,'02/08/2015 16:42:00')

declare @MenuItem table (i_menu_item_id int, s_mi_sku varchar(10))   
insert into @MenuItem values (1,'CuMa')


declare @ChoiceItem table (i_choice_item_id int, i_ticket_item_id int, i_choice_id int)
insert into @ChoiceItem
values
    (1,1,2),
    (2,1,8),
    (3,2,1),
    (4,2,8),
    (5,3,4),
    (6,4,9),
    (7,5,2),
    (8,5,8)

declare @Choices table (i_choice_id int, s_choice_sku varchar(3))
insert into @Choices
values
    (1,'Ch'),
    (2,'Bf'),
    (3,'Po'),
    (4,'To'),
    (5,'St'),
    (6,'Ve'),
    (7,'Sh$'),
    (8,'Wh'),
    (9,'Br'),
    (10,'Fr$'),
    (11,'Nr')

select 
    ti.dt_when,
    isnull(m.s_mi_sku,'') + isnull(C1.s_choice_sku,'') + isnull(C2.s_choice_sku,'') as PLU,
    count(t.i_ticket_id) as QTY
from
    @Ticket t
    inner join @TicketItem ti
        on t.i_ticket_id = ti.i_ticket_id
    inner join @MenuItem m
        on m.i_menu_item_id = ti.i_menu_item_id
    left join
            (select 
                c1.i_ticket_item_id,
                sum(case when c1.i_choice_id <=7
                        then c1.i_choice_id
                    else 0 end) c1,
                sum(case when c1.i_choice_id >=8
                        then c1.i_choice_id
                    else 0 end) c2
            from 
                @ChoiceItem c1
            group by c1.i_ticket_item_id
            ) c
        on c.i_ticket_item_id = ti.i_ticket_item_id
    left join @Choices C1
        on C1.i_choice_id = c.c1
    left join @Choices C2
        on C2.i_choice_id = c.c2
where 
    ti.dt_when between '2/8/2015 04:00:00' and '2/9/2015 03:59:00'
    and m.i_menu_item_id = 1
group by
    ti.dt_when,
    m.s_mi_sku,
    C1.s_choice_sku,
    C2.s_choice_sku
```

Comment: Thank you @GB. I'm reviewing your proposed solution. There are some issues because it appears to depend upon the Choices sku's being stored in the pre-defined order I provided in my original example. I failed to mention that choices are not in a particular order and so your use of positioning in the sub-queries defining the first left join will not work. I'm going to try to modify to use the s_choice_sku string and IN rather than the position of the choice in the Choices table.

Comment: No problem. Yes you will need to change it, not only for the sku scenario, but also for others - obviously I don't know the complexities of your situation. your problem was that you were unable to group properly... are you able to do that now based on my solution?

Comment: You solution definitely works given the example data I provided.  From that perspective, it's fair for me to mark it as an answer.   I think I'll also post whatever I finally end up with once I have something.